# How to embed a syntax object in another in TextMate language definitions, tmLanguage

Tags: syntax, visual-studio-code, tokenize, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I am trying to support Clojure's *ignore text form*, `#_`, (a sort of comment) in VS Code, which uses tmLanguage for its grammar definitions. Since it is common to disable a block of code using `#_`, I want the disabled block of code to retain its syntax highlighting and just italicize it, indicating its status.

But my lack of skills using tmLanguage seems to stop me. This is one of the failing attempts (a snippet of the `cson`):

```
  'comment-constants':
    'begin': '#_\\s*(?=\'?#?[^\\s\',"\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]+)'
    'beginCaptures':
      '0':
        'name': 'punctuation.definition.comment.begin.clojure'
    'end': '(?=[\\s\',"\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}])'
    'name': 'meta.comment-expression.clojure'
    'patterns':
      [
        {
          'include': '#constants'
        }
      ]
```

With `constants` defining some Clojure constants objects, like `keyword`:

```
  'keyword':
    'match': '(?<=(\\s|\\(|\\[|\\{)):[\\w\\#\\.\\-\\_\\:\\+\\=\\>\\<\\/\\!\\?\\*]+(?=(\\s|\\)|\\]|\\}|\\,))'
    'name': 'constant.keyword.clojure'
```

What I want to happen is that the `constants` definitions will be used ”inside” the comment. For keywords I have this (failing) spec:

```
  it "tokenizes keywords", ->
    tests =
      "meta.expression.clojure": ["(:foo)"]
      "meta.map.clojure": ["{:foo}"]
      "meta.vector.clojure": ["[:foo]"]
      "meta.quoted-expression.clojure": ["'(:foo)", "`(:foo)"]
      "meta.comment-expression.clojure": ["#_:foo"]

    for metaScope, lines of tests
      for line in lines
        {tokens} = grammar.tokenizeLine line
        expect(tokens[1]).toEqual value: ":foo", scopes: ["source.clojure", metaScope, "constant.keyword.clojure"]
```

(The last test in that list). It fails with this message:

```
Expected
{  value : ':foo',
  scopes : [ 'source.clojure', 'meta.comment-expression.clojure' ] }
to equal
{  value : ':foo',
  scopes : [ 'source.clojure', 'meta.comment-expression.clojure', 'constant.keyword.clojure' ] }.
```

Meaning I am not getting the `constant.keyword.clojure` scope in place and thus no keyword-colorization for me.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `keyword` regex starts with a lookbehind that requires that there must be a single whitespace, `(`, `[` or `{` character before keywords. The `_` from `#_` doesn't meet that requirement.

```regex
(?<=(\\s|\\(|\\[|\\{))
```

You could simply add `_` to the list of allowed characters:

```regex
(?<=(\\s|\\(|\\[|\\{|_))
```

Note that this [still wouldn't work](https://regex101.com/r/EbS9Hs/1) as-is for your `"#_:foo"` test case because of the similar lookahead at the end. You could possibly allow `$` there, make the match optional, or change the test case.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that regex site! Funny thing is that it does work. The test passes and syntax highlighting using this grammar works too. Now, I'll need to investigate why this is the case. =)